# No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider error occurred even though it already exists

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider error occurred even though QueryClient set and use QueryClientProvider were specified.[image]

After a certain period of time in the above state, sometimes normal components are displayed again, and sometimes a blank screen appears.

```
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { routes } from "./routes";
import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { getClient } from "./queryClient";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
const App = () => {
    const elem = useRoutes(routes);
    const queryClient = getClient();
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            {elem}
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
};
export default App;
```

```
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

type AnyOBJ = { [key: string]: unknown };
const BASE_URL = "https://fakestoreapi.com";

export const getClient = (() => {
    let client: QueryClient | null = null;
    return () => {
        if (!client) client = new QueryClient({});
        return client;
    };
})();

export const fetcher = async ({
    method,
    path,
    body,
    params,
}: {
    method: "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | "PATCH";
    path: string;
    body?: AnyOBJ;
    params?: AnyOBJ;
}) => {
    const url = `${BASE_URL}${path}`;
    const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
        method,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": BASE_URL,
        },
    };
    try {
        const res = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
        const json = await res.json();
        return json;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

export const QueryKeys = {
    PRODUCTS: "PRODUCTS",
};
```

version
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.35.0",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.35.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-query": "^3.39.3",

Comment: I tried running your code online with exact same dependency versions, and it is working just fine. Your dependency tree might be incorrectly resolved. Deleting and reinstalling `node_modules` might fix the issue. And, I also believe you no longer need v3 `react-query` since you're already using v4 `@tanstack/react-query`.